# Problems read files in python:UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd5 in position 168: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, python-3.x

I try to open the text file and it does not work

```
with open('quiz.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#35>", line 2, in <module>
    lines=f.readlines()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd5 in position 168: invalid continuation byte
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I open a text file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40096612/how-do-i-open-a-text-file-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Invalid continuation byte = not unicode = probably a binary file.

```py
with open('quiz.txt', 'rb') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
```

will open the file in bytes mode.

Another possibility is that you are executing this in your shell, and the program looks for stuff only in the working directory.

```py
import os
os.chdir('/path/to/your/file/excluding/file/name')
with open('quiz.txt', 'rb') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
```